# Tags unit-tests, MUnit

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging, tag-synonyms

I suggest making [unit-tests](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unit-tests) synonymous with [munit](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/munit), with [unit-tests](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unit-tests) being the primary. I can't suggest this through the regular way because I don't have enough rep in the tag.

I don't know if there is any work (retagging/detagging) to be done, but I would be glad to help.  There are not many questions in either category.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've synonymized [munit](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/munit) with [unit-tests](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unit-tests).