# Tags related to Testing & Verification

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-synonyms

Currently there is the [unit-tests](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unit-tests) tag with [munit](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/munit) [as a synonym](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1941/18476).
There are also the tags [testing-framework](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/testing-framework), [verificationtest](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verificationtest), and [testreport](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/testreport), which don't have a usage guidance or tag wiki.

In my opinion there should only be one tag that covers the topics of the Wolfram Language Guide [Systematic Testing & Verification](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SystematicTestingAndVerification.html) and the [Using the Testing Framework](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UsingTheTestingFramework.html) Wolfram Language Tutorial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tags [unit-tests](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unit-tests), [munit](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/munit), [testing-framework](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/testing-framework), [verificationtest](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verificationtest), and [testreport](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/testreport) should all become synonyms for the new tag [testing-and-verification](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/testing-and-verification).

Comment: `@name` comments do not work unless the target has already commended on a given post, therefore I never saw your comment.

Comment: Kuba is going to handle this now.

Comment: I never intend to be hard to reach.  Next time please use the **flag** feature and select **in need of moderator intervention** if a simple comment is or would be ineffective.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard OK, thanks for the feedback. Never had the impression that it was intentional. Until now I considered flagging for moderator intervention is only for serious stuff.

Comment: True, it shouldn't be used indiscriminately or as the *first* course of action, but this is a good example where it would have been appropriate as indeed moderator intervention was needed and comments were ineffective.  Another example would be if you have an answer for a closed question; just **flag** it and explain rather than voting to reopen and trying to convince people to join you.  Almost always I would reopen in such a case.

Answer (score 1):

The tags [testing-framework](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/testing-framework), [verificationtest](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verificationtest), and [testreport](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/testreport) should become synonymous to [unit-tests](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unit-tests).